# Get content inside nested div class using Goute PHP

Tags: php, laravel, domcrawler

Sorry for bad english.
So i want to scrap some content from the website, but the div classes are nested and confusing me.

Basically the structure is :

```
<div id="gsc_vcd_table">
  <div class="gs_scl">
    <div class="gsc_vcd_field">
      Pengarang
    </div>
    <div class="gsc_vcd_value">
      I Anggara Wijaya, Djoko Budiyanto Setyohadi
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gs_scl">
    <div class="gsc_vcd_field">
      Tanggal Terbit
    </div>
    <div class="gsc_vcd_value">
      2017/3/1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get text  **I Anggara Wijaya, Djoko Budiyanto Setyohadi** from **Pengarang** field and also get **2017/3/1** from **Tanggal Terbit** field.

```
$crawlerdetail=$client->request('GET',$detail);
   $detailscholar=$crawlerdetail->filter('div.gsc_vcd_table');
   foreach ($detailscholar as $key) 
   {
        $keyCrawler=new Crawler($key);
        $pengarang=($scCrawler->filter('div.gsc_vcd_value')->count()) ? $scCrawler->filter('div.gsc_vcd_value')->text() : '';
        echo $pengarang;
   }
```

Help me please.

Comment: Why don't use `preg_match_all` or `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` ?

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z.how to use that ?

Comment: I will write a simple code for you, but before you sure about `<div>` in line 9 and 17, I thinks that must be `</div>`, and also `=` chars in class attr, in lines: 3, 6, 11, 14 , maybe you don't give any good results because your code is not valid.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z.i've update the structure , please take a look.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z.sorry i just found the solution, the variable $scCrawler must be  $keyCrawler. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) class.

See this code:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<div id="gsc_vcd_table">
  <div class="gs_scl">
    <div class="gsc_vcd_field">
      Pengarang
    </div>
    <div class="gsc_vcd_value">
      I Anggara Wijaya, Djoko Budiyanto Setyohadi
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gs_scl">
    <div class="gsc_vcd_field">
      Tanggal Terbit
    </div>
    <div class="gsc_vcd_value">
      2017/3/1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result1 = $xml->xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'gsc_vcd_field')]");
$result2 = $xml->xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'gsc_vcd_value')]");

foreach ($result1 as $key => $node) {
    echo "FIELD: $result1[$key] , VALUE: $result2[$key]<br>\n";
}
```

And also for get xpath pattern of any elements, you can use inspect in chrome, and Copy XPath.

Another solution is use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), see:

```
preg_match_all('/<div class="gsc_vcd_field">\r\n(.*?)\r\n.*<\/div>\r\n.*<div class="gsc_vcd_value">\r\n(.*?)\r\n.*<\/div>/', $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
    echo "FIELD: " . $matches[1][$key] . " , VALUE: " . $matches[2][$key] . "<br>\n";
}
```